# How to write list of string from binary string?

Tags: python, pcap

I am trying to write program to analyze .pcap file. I am using next code to write all content into the list:

```
data = []
for i in range (len(capfile.packets)):
    data.append((ip.IP(binascii.unhexlify(ethernet.Ethernet(capfile.packets[i].raw()).payload))))
```

Now I want to create new *.txt file which will have an output of:

```
print(data[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can print to a file in following way:

```
# open a file handle in append mode
txt_file = open('samplefile.txt', 'a') 

# print with file argument will direct the output to the file
print(data[i], file=txt_file)

# close the file handle
txt_file.close()
```

Putting this in your loop:

```
data = []
txt_file = open('samplefile.txt', 'a')

for i in range (len(capfile.packets)):
    data.append((ip.IP(binascii.unhexlify(ethernet.Ethernet(capfile.packets[i].raw()).payload))))
    print(data[i], file=txt_file)

txt_file.close()
```